# Alert Box Position in IPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In IPad we are facing an issue with positioning the customized alert boxes. 
After exploring in google i had maintained the approrpaite css to have alert boxes in the center of the screen with top as 50%.
We have a requirement Wherein the alert boxes should be positioned relative to the text box position when a validation message fires. In Ipad its taking the entire screen and positioning the alert box in a particular position.
We want it to be positioned relative to the text box position in IPad.

We have altogether 7 jsp pages included in a main jsp page. When i click on the text box which is in 7th jsp page i.e the bottom of the main page, the alert box should appear there itself. But, it is not the case with the css.

Please help us on the same ....

Following is the css i had applied :

```
.white_content {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 25%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 20%;
    border: 1px solid orange;
    z-index:1002;
    overflow: auto; 
}
```

ScrollTop attribute is not working in Ipad. Unable to get scrollTop value while scrolling in Ipad. Is there any alternative for scrollTop attribute.

In Ipad, Dialog box is getting scrolled with the body i.e screen. How to make dialog as fixed in Ipad eventhough the body scrolls.Please share the solution.

Comment: Please provide us code related to same

Comment: use http://jqueryui.com/position/